# Populate AngularJS {{expression}} within ng-repeat using a second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, laravel

I'm completely rebuilding my website (originally hacked together with Wordpress) using Laravel and AngularJS. It's been a massive learning experience and I think I'm nearly there but for one problem.

On my site 'schemes' (or courses) are made up of 'units' which are made up of 'lessons'. Retrieving this data is fine, using Eloquent I retrieve valid JSON like this made up example...

```
[
{
    "id": "1", //Scheme Id
    "title": "Sports",
    "description": "This is a Sports course!",
    "units": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Tennis",
            "lessons": [
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "title": "Serving"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7",
                    "title": "Hitting the ball with top-spin"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Athletics",
            "lessons": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "title": "Long Jump"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "title": "Hurdling Technique"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "title": "Golf",
            "lessons": [
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "title": "Pitching"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "title": "Putting"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
....
]
```

Separately I have a simple array of completed lesson ids for a particular user like this...

```
[2, 6, 8, 9] ///User has completed lessons with ids of 2,6,8 and 9
```

In my view I'm using nested ng-repeat loops like so...

```
...
<div ng-controller="SchemesController">
<div ng-repeat="scheme in schemes">
    <h1>{{scheme.title}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="unit in scheme.units">
        <h3>{{unit.title}}</h3>
        <div ng-repeat="lesson in unit.lessons">
            <div>{{lesson.title}}: {{status}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><!--[end of ng-controller="SchemesController"]-->
....
```

SchemesController (v simple!) looks like this...

```
   var app = angular.module('schemesApp', []);

   app.controller('SchemesController', function($scope){
    $scope.schemes=jsonData;
   });
```

The problem is I have no idea how to populate the {{status}} field which I want to state simply 'Complete' or 'Incomplete. I investigated whether I could somehow add this info to my original array like this...

```
"lessons": [
            {
                "id": "6",
                "title": "Serving",
                "status": "Complete" //populated somehow
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "title": "Hitting the ball with top-spin",

            }
        ]
```

but I got nowhere slowly. Is there a way to do this (I've played around with underscore.js and felt this could help?).

Or do I populate {{status}} from creating and calling a javascript function?!?

ANY help that anyone could offer would be incredible. I'm a school teacher and for some sadistic reason I find a bit of programming/web design a fun use of my spare time so I apologise if this is a stupid question. THANKS in advance!!!

btw if anyone has a better 'title' for this question then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't need to persist the status back to the database...

This is where you're having the problem:

```
<div>{{lesson.title}}: {{status}}</div>
```

You really don't need to store the status in your data model, because it's just used for presentation purposes.

Let's say your array of completed lessons is defined like this:

```
$scope.completedLessons = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // Or however you'd assign it
```

You need to create a function in your scope like this:

```
$scope.isLessonCompleted = function(lessonId) {
  return $scope.completedLessons.indexOf(lessonId) > -1;
};
```

Then you need to change the html from above to this:

```
 <div>{{lesson.title}}: {{isLessonCompleted(lesson.id) && 'Complete' || 'Incomplete'}}</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to return:
`$scope.isLessonCompleted = function(lessonId) { return $scope.completedLessons.indexOf(lessonId) > -1; };`

Comment: Thanks... too much CoffeeScript

Comment: Thanks to you both (@Scottux) for helping. Rather than just copy and paste, I'd like to know I vaguely follow it too! This code calls the 'isLessonCompleted' function - passing the current lesson.id from the loop. This id is then located within the completedLessons array, if it is located then 'indexOf' returns a positive number. Have I understood that correctly? Hopefully the final noob question - Where does that 'isLessonCompleted' function go - inside the controller, as a service/factory...? Cheers again!

Comment: You are understanding everything perfectly. `isLessonCompleted` goes in your 'SchemesController` attached to the `$scope`. All methods called from the DOM in Angular have to exist in the scope that wraps them. If this is common functionality throughout your application, you should write a utility service that provides an `isLessonCompleted` function That you could inject into multiple controllers/directives. In either case, you'll still have to attach a method to the scope that wraps your element so you can call it from the DOM

Comment: You've been an absolute star but if you could show me where exactly it should go? Set this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9PXrK/) up - think I'm still putting the function in the wrong place as it breaks everything where I've put it!!! I'm a teacher and I've never looked forward more to giving someone a 'tick'...

Comment: In the fiddle you need to change `var completedLessons` to `$scope.completedLessons`. Then in your `isLessonCompleted` function you need to add `lessonId = parseInt(lessonId, 10);` before the return statement, because you're passing in strings. Then it will work.

Comment: You're a star. Thanks for ALL your time!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/scottux/5LEqD/ - Your ids need to be globally unique or you need to extend this to account for lessons with ids only unique to their units/schemes.

Comment: @Scottux Thanks for your example, some nice bits and pieces in there! I can't get my head around why the unique thing is a problem though? If a `student` has completed a `lesson`, I want that to be marked as complete in any `unit` in which it appears and a lesson can appear in multiple units. Also the array against which the lessons ids are checked only contains completed lesson ids...? See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richf/zqY7W/1/) where it seems to be working ok. Not being rude, just like to fully understand!

Comment: Oh I see, then the lesson id just needs to be unique and remove the unit bit then. I thought there were duplicated ids. Didn't mean to confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

If lessons are also a model and each lesson should have a status, which isn't a column/field in your table but is something you'll add logic to determine, you could add a custom model accessor by adding the following to your `models/Lesson.php`:

```
// Append custom accessor attributes
protected $appends = ['status'];

public function getStatusAttribute() {
    // Add logic here
    return 'Complete';
}
```

This way, when you use Eloquent to retrieve your data, you'll also see a `status` attribute as part of the object, so you could then access it as usual `$lesson->status` (PHP) or `lesson.status` (JS).

For more information, see the official Laravel documentation on [accessors and mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: Hi David, I'm generating the initial data using `code`$schemes = Scheme::with( array( 'units', 'units.lessons') )->get();`code`
How can I pass the lesson_id in to the logic section to query with?

Comment: Hi,

When the model is being processed, you have access to all of the object data in the accessor so you'd simply do `$this->id`.

Comment: Excellent - I've got it working this way now too. Sorry I can't accept two answers because they're both brilliant solutions, had a feeling there would be a couple of ways to achieve the result. Cheers again!